# User access issue in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, privileges

In my oracle DB, i have a user named `test` this user has `DML_ROLE` in the DB. And, i have provided insert/update/delete/select access to `DML_ROLE` on a table named `hdr_detail`.

But, when user `test` execute an update query on `hdr_detail` table its getting error message as `Returned error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`. It works fine when i provide the access directly to the user.

I'm confused why this error shows up only when i provide the access through role.

**Table structure:**

```
COLUMN NAME          DATA TYPE
PERIOD               NUMBER
HDR_ID               VARCHAR2(50)
```

**Query i use to update:**

```
update test_sch.hdr_detail set period=201108 where hdr_id = 'check';
```

**Statement i use to grant:**

```
grant insert,select,update,delete on test_sch.hdr_detail to dml_role;
```

`select * from dba_role_privs where grantee like 'TEST'` returns the following result

```
GRANTEE GRANTED_ROLE  ADMIN_OPTION  DEFAULT_ROLE
TEST    DML_ROLE      NO            NO
```

`select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name like 'HDR_DETAIL'` returns the following result

```
GRANTEE    OWNER       TABLE_NAME   GRANTOR     PRIVILEGE   GRANTABLE    HIERARCHY
DML_ROLE   TEST_SCH    HDR_DETAIL   TEST_SCH    DELETE      NO           NO
DML_ROLE   TEST_SCH    HDR_DETAIL   TEST_SCH    INSERT      NO           NO
DML_ROLE   TEST_SCH    HDR_DETAIL   TEST_SCH    SELECT      NO           NO
DML_ROLE   TEST_SCH    HDR_DETAIL   TEST_SCH    UPDATE      NO           NO
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. Reply in comment if any more information is needed about this issue.

Comment: How is the user attemptign to make the update? Directly through SQL*Plus or an interface like that or through an application?

Comment: is there any public synonym in the database like hdr_detail? possibly your user see another table.

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: @Florin: Nope. I tried executing with the schema name, still the same error:(

Comment: @ollie: It dont have any triggers.

Comment: OK, could you edit your question to add the table structure and the exact update query that is causing the issue as well as the grant syntax please? There might be something that we've missed.

Comment: and select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name like 'HDR_DETAIL' ?

Comment: Try setting the role as the users default role: ALTER USER test DEFAULT ROLE dml_role;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the role as the users default role:

```
ALTER USER test DEFAULT ROLE dml_role;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with how you are accessing the databse object HDR_DETAIL.

From Don burleson (http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/roles_security.htm):

> Oracle roles have some limitations. In particular object privileges are granted through Oracle roles can not be used when writing PL/SQL code. When writing PL/SQL code, you must have direct grants to the objects in the database that your code is accessing.

If your user is issuing the UPDATE through an application or PL/SQL block then it will not use the role-based permissions. If this is the case you will have to grant the permissions directly.

Comment: No. User is executing through sql*plus only. Its a normal SQL statement "Update hdr_detail set <field_name>=<value>"

Comment: Try setting the role as the users default role: ALTER USER test
DEFAULT ROLE dml_role;

Comment: @Ollie: It seems that you're mixing up _writing PL/SQL code_ and _executing PL/SQL code_. PL/SQL code is usually executed with the definer's rights.

Comment: @Codo, yes, can't see the wood for the trees today :-)

Comment: Thanks ollie. That solved my issue :)  Please post your comment as an answer. So that i can accept it.

Comment: @Vivek: What exactly solved the problem? I guess it was the missing _DEFAULT_ keyword.

Comment: @Codo: dml_role has `update` access on my table but the `test` user is not having DML_ROLE as the default role. So, oracle is not considering the access dml_role has on my table. Now after changing dml_role as the default role of user `test` it worked fine. We can make this change using the DDL posted by OLLIE above

Answer (score 0):

That seems impossible.
Are you sure that your user connect to correct DB, schema, and query the right table?
I'm stunned.

Pls try

```
select * from test_sch.hdr_detail
```

wiht test user.